# Centered text and pictures in the same line

Tags: html, css, format

I am making a footer for my site and was wondering if it is possible to have text centered on the page and have a few pictures on the right side of the page in the same line as the text.

Whenever I center the text using `text-align:center`, the pictures just get pushed down to the line below.

`HTML`:

```
<div class="footer">
    <hr id="break">
    <p id="credit">Created by:</p>
    <a class="picture" id="linkedin" href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="Pictures/linkedin.png" width="20px" height="20px"/>
    </a>
    <a class="picture" id="email" href="#" target="_top">
        <img src="Pictures/email.png" width="20px" height="20px"/>
    </a>
    <a class="picture" id="github" href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="Pictures/github.png" width="40px" height="10.45px"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
#break {
    margin:0;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:rgba(191,191,191,.65);
}

#credit {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:44%;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.picture {
    padding-top:10px;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}

#linkedin {
    padding-right:50px;
}

#email {
    padding-right:15px;
}

#github {
    padding-right:15px;
}
```

Comment: can you please write link of your site or in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
.footer { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;}
```

This will align all the images and the text in the center of the footer.

If you want space between images and text try this:

```
.footer { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;}

.footer > *{margin: auto; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, .65);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

#credit {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.footer a {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p id="credit">Created by:</p>
  <a class="picture" id="linkedin" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/20/20">
  </a>
  <a class="picture" id="email" href="#" target="_top">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/20/20">
  </a>
  <a class="picture" id="github" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/40/10">
  </a>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, .65);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#credit {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  flex: 100;
}

.footer a {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p id="credit">Created by:</p>
  <a class="picture" id="linkedin" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/20/20">
  </a>
  <a class="picture" id="email" href="#" target="_top">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/20/20">
  </a>
  <a class="picture" id="github" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/40/10">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way that the created by could be centered on the page?

Comment: @MattStrenk yes, see that again.